# How to skip iteration of results in one foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have two `foreach` loops as shown in the code :

```
DataTable dtx = GetAmens(Id);
if (dtx.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    strAmen += @"<ul class='col-md-6'>";
    int c = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtx.Rows)
    {
        if (c >= ((dtx.Rows.Count / 2) + (dtx.Rows.Count % 2))) break;
        strAmen += "<li class='enabled'>" + dr["amen"].ToString() + "</li>";
        c++;
    }

    strAmen += @"</ul><ul class='col-md-6'>";
    c = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtx.Rows)
    {
        strAmen += "<li class='enabled'>" + dr["amen"].ToString() + "</li>";
        c++;
    }
    strAmen += @"</ul>";
}
```

there are 7 values in datatable.

first `foreach` is iterating through 4 elements.

Now i want that the second `foreach` statement must not iterate through the 4 elements (result came in 1st `foreach` statement)

And instead iterate through the remaining 3 elements.

can anyone suggest any changes required to get such results???
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use regular for loop instead?

Comment: Replace `foreach` to `for`.

Comment: If you really want to keep `foreach` and you don't need to use those elements anymore, you could possibly remove those first elements from your DataTable after iterating over them in the first `foreach`?

Comment: @Isuka i need all those elements.

Comment: is it possible to remove those first elements from DataTable after iterating over them in the first foreach & iterate remaining in second foreach? 
if yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the group in two using LINQ. Then go over the groups and add them one by one to the result:

```
var columns = dtx.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select((r, i) => new {Row = r, Group = i >= ((dtx.Rows.Count / 2) + (dtx.Rows.Count % 2))}).GroupBy(r => r.Group);

foreach (var group in columns)
{
    strAmen += @"<ul class='col-md-6'>";

    foreach (DataRow dr in group.Select(g => g.Row))
    {
        strAmen += "<li class='enabled'>" + dr["amen"].ToString() + "</li>";
    }

    strAmen += @"</ul>";
}
```

Comment: I edited your code right? The first line groups the results. Then it is basically the same as your code.

Comment: You missed one angular bracket, i added it. but now it's showing following error : "datarow does not contain definition for select".
Can you please recheck your edits?

Comment: you are still missing to close the angular bracket here : 
    var columns = dtx.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select((r, i) => new {Row = r, Group = i >= ((dtx.Rows.Count / 2) + (dtx.Rows.Count % 2))).GroupBy(r => Group);


When i made corrections it says : "foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type ?"

Comment: Thanks, But it's not working as visual studio throwing "Group is a type, which is not valid in this context"
and also "foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type ?"

Comment: Argh, can't type it right without VS. Now it should do.

Comment: Errors gone with data as well. Now it's not returning any results.

Comment: Are there any rows in your table?

Comment: yes. there are 7 rows in the table.
As my original code goes.. first foreach will filter out 4 out of 7 and will display it. second foreach will fetch 7 out of 7 and will display. But what i want is that second foreach should skip 4 rows came in 1st foreach & should return remaining 3.

Comment: is it possible to remove those first elements from DataTable after iterating over them in the first foreach & iterate remaining in second foreach?

Comment: can u give some suggestions? demo code or something?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a new variable and for loop if you can use it.
This will make sure that you have to loop only 'n' times(n is number of records).

if you have some logic with variable "c" then use a new variable in inner for loop, instead of reusing "c"

```
 DataTable dtx = GetAmens(Id);
 string strAmen = "";
 if (dtx.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     strAmen += @"<ul class='col-md-6'>";
     int c = 0;

     foreach (DataRow dr in dtx.Rows)
     {
         if (c >= ((dtx.Rows.Count / 2) + (dtx.Rows.Count % 2)))
         {
             strAmen += @"</ul><ul class='col-md-6'>";
             for (c=c; c < dtx.Rows.Count; c++)
             {
                  strAmen += "<li class='enabled'>" + dtx.Rows[c]["amen"].ToString() + "</li>";
             }
             strAmen += @"</ul>";
             break;
         }

         strAmen += "<li class='enabled'>" + dr["amen"].ToString() + "</li>";
         c++;
     }
 }
```